# Database technology choice based on an use case

Tags: mongodb, redis, database

I am creating an API Limiter, and I am having issues deciding on what system to use for data storage.

It is really clear that I am going to need a volatile storage, plus a persistent storage.

On the volatile I want to store a key-value like this:

```
read:14522145 100
read:99885669 16
read:78951585 100
```

This is a key composed of: `{action}:{client}` and an integer value (available credits).

On the persistent, I want to keep a record of all resource outages.

The algorithm (pseudo-code) is pretty simple:

```
MAX_AMOUNT = 100
call(action, client, cost) {
  key = action + ":" + client
  if (volatileStorage.hasKey(key)) {
    value = volatileStorage.getValue(key)
    if (value >= cost) {
      volatileStorage.setValue(key, value - cost)
      return true
    } else {
      persistentStorage.logOutage(method, client, cost)
      return false
    }
  } else {        
      volatileStorage.setValue(key, MAX_AMOUNT)
      return call(action, client, cost)
  }
}
```

There is a parallel process that runs every `N` seconds for each `method`, that increases all keys `{action}:*` by M, up to O.

Additionally, I want to remove from the volatile store all items older (not modified since) than P seconds.

So basically every action is `action<N, M, O, P>`. For instance, reading users is increased every 1 second, by 5 points, up to 100, and removed after 60 seconds of inactivity: `read_users<1, 5, 100, 60>`.

So I need a volatile storage that:

1. Reads really quick, without consuming too many resources (what's the point of rejecting a call, if the process is more expensive than the very own call).
2. Allows TTL on items.
3. Can, with good performance, increase all keys matching a pattern (`read_users:*`) without getting out of a defined limit.

and a persistent storage that:

1. Is also quick.
2. Can handle loads of registers.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer but an opinion: there are existing rate limiters that you would be better off using instead of making your own. Getting it right is tricky, so adopting a production-proven implementation is not only easier but also safer.

For example, the [Generic cell rate algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_cell_rate_algorithm) is nothing short of plain magic and has several Redis implementations, including:

- As a Ruby gem (that uses server-side Lua): https://github.com/rwz/redis-gcra
- As a (v4) module: https://github.com/brandur/redis-cell/

Of course, there are many more Redis-based rate limiters - I use Google to find them ;)

Comment: I'm afraid that, for reasons beyond the scope this post, I need to implement it myself.